# Major tick labels on 10 week increments, minor ticks on 2 week increments

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to set up a graph to show some data over time, and I want to show specific dates as the x-axis major and minor ticks.  I am trying to set up Major ticks every 10 weeks of time, and Minor ticks every 2 weeks of time.

The problem I am running into is that the minor and major ticks line up every 5th tick.  Is it possible to remove the minor ticks where there is a major tick?

My code:

```
tenw_locator = matplotlib.dates.WeekdayLocator(matplotlib.dates.MO, interval=10)
twow_locator = matplotlib.dates.WeekdayLocator(matplotlib.dates.MO, interval=2)

ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(tenw_locator)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(matplotlib.dates.AutoDateFormatter(tenw_locator))
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(twow_locator)
ax.xaxis.set_minor_formatter(matplotlib.dates.AutoDateFormatter(twow_locator))

plt.setp(ax.xaxis.get_majorticklabels(), rotation=70)
plt.setp(ax.xaxis.get_minorticklabels(), rotation=90)
```

The problem is that because the major tick labels are rotated differently, they overlap with the minor tick labels.

I am looking at the `ax.xaxis.set_ticks` function, but it would mean manually calculating the minor tick dates, as it would need to exclude every 5th 2-week increment.

Does matplotlib support any way to hide the minor tick labels where there are major tick labels?